# Can an Instance of SQL Server Express 2008 R2 be used as a Master Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

For multi-server administration, can an instance of SQL Server Express 2008 R2 be used as a SQL Server Agent Master Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because SQL Express doesn't have the SQL Agent.

Comment: Oh, right. Duh!